# Unzipping on Windows Phone Mango

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

I am looking to extract a zip file from a url. What is the best way you would recommend to do this?
Basically, I want to point my phone app to a Zip url and have the files in it for processing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to download a GZIP file from web to windowsphone7, unzip the contents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707917/how-to-download-a-gzip-file-from-web-to-windowsphone7-unzip-the-contents)

Answer (score 0):

```
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip;

MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(data);
        ZipFile zipped = null;
        zipped = new ZipFile(mem);
        IEnumerator enum1 = zipped.GetEnumerator();
   while (enum1.MoveNext())
        {
            ZipEntry entry1 = (ZipEntry)enum1.Current;
            Stream memst = zipped.GetInputStream(entry1);
            long len = entry1.Size;
            cmdresp = new byte[len];
            memst.Read(cmdresp, 0, (int)len);
        }
```